# How do I delete two sides of a rectangle in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this rectangle with of course a border around it on all four sides. I would like to delete two of these sides so you have a rectangle with only two colored sides instead of four. The problem is that the scissor tool does not work.

Comment: Be aware opened paths with fills applied can cause issues outside of Illustrator. It is best to *always* used closed paths if you have a fill applied.

Comment: Hi 2hTu2, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add an anchor point with the pen tool in the middle of the path(s) you want to delete, then select that anchor point with the white arrow (direct selection tool) and delete it!

## Edit... as requested

You do what I suggested above for one side.

Then you can do what I suggested above for the other side as well.

[image: How to remove one side of a rectangle, or 2!]

If you want to keep some filling, you'll need to add a rectangle with no stroke and send it to the back... with your 2 strokes left on the foreground :D

---

If you need to delete 2 paths that touch each others, simply use the white arrow (direct selection tool) and select the corner of these 2 paths... then press "delete"

Comment: What's the purpose of adding an anchor then deleting it? Wouldn't it be quicker to just use the Direct Selection tool to select the sides then delete them? Like so: http://gfycat.com/ComposedThinAtlanticbluetang (my screen capturer doesn't show my cursor but you get the idea)

Comment: Old habits from Illustrator legacy and using anchor points to delete segments or parts of segments?

Comment: Understandable, we all have our ways of doing things :) I just wasn't sure if adding an anchor then deleting it does something special that I'm unaware of

Answer (score 4):

You should think about the `Stroke` as a separate entity. Draw your rectangle with just a `Fill` and no `Stroke` then use either *Pen* or *Rectangle* to create the `Stroke` on the sides.

Alternatively if you already drew your Rectangle (or any shape really) with a `Fill` and `Stroke` then you can use *Expand* to separate the Stroke from the Fill and then manipulate it how you'd like to.

Just use `Groups` (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to keep the parts together.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, enabling to keep the fill and all (and group them as a bonus, to keep them together!)